He’s gone to work for the opposition

He’s gone to work for the opposition.

work is a noun or verb?
I think this is the same or similar question as "go to work".

This question is similar to: But the following day the boy goes to work for a dairy farmer. (work is a noun or a verb?). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As I said in a comment on the duplicate, context will decide. But for this example, noun is far less likely—ridiculously unlikely, in fact. Anything I could imagine to make the noun meaning work would be so contrived as to be part of a joke.

It work was intended to be a noun, then it would be referring to his place of work. In that case, as a stand alone sentence, it doesn't entirely make sense.

@AndyBonner - you do find, in the UK, (and I hate it!) people casually using 'work' as a noun meaning 'my employer', e.g. I wanted a week off at Christmas, but work won't let me or When I am sick I have to phone work before 10am.

He's gone to play for Real Madrid. These are to infinitive clauses.

I'd call it a verb. He isn't going to his regular or habitual workplace ('his work'). If, in a team sports match (cricket, football, etc), we said that one of the players had decided to 'go to play' for the other side or opposition, what would you call 'play'? A verb or a noun? The essence of the saying in your example is that the person has left one team or group in order to work for an opposing one thus making 'work' a verb.
